# Check Map data types in generics

Tags: flutter, dart, generics, types

I am making my own `List` and want to add logic to have different process based on the data type of `E`.
`E = int` is not a problem, but `E = Map` has an unwanted behavior.

For example, I want to treat all of `E = Map<int, int>`, `E = Map<int, String>` and `E = Map` as `Map`. However, `==` and `is` seem to consider these 3 are different. Could you help me with this issue?

my_list.dart

```
class MyList<E> extends ListBase<E> {
  final List<E> _list = <E>[];

  MyList() {
    print('E: $E');
    if (E == int) {
      print('int!!');
    } else if (E == HashMap || E is HashMap) {
      print('HashMap!!');
    } else if (E == LinkedHashMap || E is LinkedHashMap) {
      print('LinkedHashMap!!');
    } else if (E == SplayTreeMap || E is SplayTreeMap) {
      print('SplayTreeMap!!');
    } else if (E == Map || E is Map) {
      print('Map!!');
    }
  }

  // Other methods...
}
```

my_list_test.dart

```
void main() {
  test('Test MyList', () {
    final MyList<int> list = MyList<int>();
    final MyList<LinkedHashMap<int, String>> list1 =
        MyList<LinkedHashMap<int, String>>();
    final MyList<HashMap<int, String>> list2 = MyList<HashMap<int, String>>();
    final MyList<Map<int, int>> list3 = MyList<Map<int, int>>();
    final MyList<Map<int, String>> list4 = MyList<Map<int, String>>();
    final MyList<Map> list5 = MyList<Map>();
  });
}
```

Actual result

```
E: int
int!!
E: LinkedHashMap<int, String>
E: HashMap<int, String>
E: Map<int, int>
E: Map<int, String>
E: Map<dynamic, dynamic>
Map!!
✓ Test MyList
```

Expected Result

```
E: int
int!!
E: LinkedHashMap<int, String>
LinkedHashMap!! // This is not shown in the actual result
E: HashMap<int, String>
HashMap!! // This is not shown in the actual result
E: Map<int, int>
Map!! // This is not shown in the actual result
E: Map<int, String>
Map!! // This is not shown in the actual result
E: Map<dynamic, dynamic>
Map!!
✓ Test MyList
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `E is Map` is that [the `is` operator is True if the object has the specified type](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators), but the type of `E` is actually not `E` but rather type `Type`.

```dart
if (E is Type) {
  print('Type!!!');
}
```

The problem with `E == Map` is that `Map` is a raw type which is equivalent to `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`. If `E` is any other type of `Map` you will get false.

What you can do is check the type of an instance of `E` rather than `E` itself. For example, something like:

```dart
void add(E element) {
  if (element is Map) {
    print('Map!!');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how Flutter/Dart typing works. You can not explicitly check two types with generics (example on List): comparing of

```
List<int>
```

and

```
List
```

will always return false.

If you really need to compare two generic types then you can unpack them using generic helper to Type and try to compare them e.g. via string representations.

Helper:

```
Type _unpackedType<T>() => T;
```

Example usage:

```
void _check<T>() {
  print(_unpackedType<T>());
  print(_unpackedType<List>());
}


void main() {
  _check<List<int>>();
}
```

This will result into output as:

```
List<int>
List<dynamic>
```

Unfortunately these types can not be compared explicitly as the result will always be negative because of how Dart works with types, but as you can see the representation is comparable enough, so if you need such strict comparison you can simply normalise the output and remove the generic part from type string and compare type string representations. This will be relevant for any generic type and will work for you case.